# insert data as an array in MySql using laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

How i can insert multiple id of a table in a single field of another table using laravel 5.4 for exemple :

```
--------------
   field 
--------------
  2-6-12-7...     
--------------
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you can make multiple separated ids as a string and then you can insert. Before inserting you have to sure that the field type is varchar or string.

**Code Example**

```
$userIds = User::select('id')->get()->toArray();

$joinIds = implode("-", array_column($userIds, "id"));
```

Now I will Insert into another table which name is Post and has a column name is user_id. The column user_id type will be varchar or string.

```
$post = new Post();
$post->user_id = $joinIds;
$post->save();
```